# jquery Checkbox Selection to manipulate a table of row

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need to select the header checkbox when all the rows are selected.

I used logic to keep a count of the number of rows checked if it's equal to row_count,I need to select the header checkbox

The problem is I cannot access the header checkbox through DOM because of the browser restriction
I'm using the following jquery code to get it worked but it's not working as expected

```
    var check_box =  fw.component_helper.get_table_column_editor(fw.form_constants.CHECK_BOX);//header checkbox 
$("check_box").attr('checked',true);
```

**Note: fw is my own defined framework**

Please suggest what's wrong with this approach

Answer (score 0):

use prop instead of attr. What is "$('check_box')". Define weather it is class or id. you selector is wrong here I thing this could be problem.

```
$(".check_box").prop('checked',true);
```

or

```
$("#check_box").prop('checked',true);
```

or

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: I tried prop but it seems my jqery version is old it does not suppport prop and I can't update jquery framework constraint

Comment: have you checked the selector which i mention in my answer. You selected the checkbox wrongly(i.e: $('check_box')).

Comment: No still not working it's throwing error Object [object object] had no method prop

Comment: $("check_box").attr('checked',true); it this code you have added any class or id for 'check_box'. Please check it. What is "check_box". jQuery not able to find 'check_box' without class or id